# How should I use Executor insteand of AsyncTask or IntentService for queueing task on Android?

Tags: android, concurrency, service, android-asynctask, executor

1. Is it a good solution or not?
2. How to implement?
3. When should I shutdown properly? I shutdown it onDestroy() in the Activity, then relaunch my app as soon as possible. It causes a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`, why? Does anyone know its lifecycle?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: After I changed to create the Executor in onCreate than static, the exeception is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, I think so. AsyncTask is used for those tasks which will update UI. Sorry I am not familiar with IntentService.
2. Create an Application object which implements [android.app.Application](http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) interface. Create Executor in the onCreate method. You can get your Application object using following statement:

> MyApplication app = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
>
> I am not sure what you mean by "app destory". I think you can shutdown Executor in Application's onTerminate method and onLowMemory method.

Comment: Sorry about my typo, I mean onDestroy() in the Activity. I have no idea why I close the App (shutdown the Executor) and relaunch the app again, it got crash by the RejectedExecutionException. It seems to execute the task when it is not completely shutdown and use the old executor again. Why?

Comment: Maybe you can post some of your code on, so that we can know more about your question. BTW, I think it is better to create and shutdown Executor in Application object(like I said in my answer to your second question), since Executor is a heavy object, and user can launch and exit Activity very frequently, but Application object will be there unless the app process is killed. And if Executor is created in Activity, it is hard to reuse the Executor from outside of this Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think that's why it can not use in the Activity's lifecycle.

Comment: onTerminate() method of Application is not guaranteed to run if the process is killed.

Answer (score 2):

I just figure out the `AsyncYask` already implemented the Java's concurrency executor with core_pool_size 5 and max_pool_size 128. That's great!